# Vectors throwing Resources$NotFoundException after updating support library from 23.v to 24.v

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-xml, android-vectordrawable

Everything was working fine while on support lib 23 but after updating support lib to ver 24, i am getting crash exceptions on pre-lollipop devices for layer-list which have vector drawable in them which ultimately leads to Resources$NotFoundException.

Any idea why?

FYI, everything else is working fine, eg. vector in imageview, runtime vector drawable usage and yes i have configured gradle properly.

Adding stack trace for better understanding.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class ...BlaView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class ...View
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17483)
       at ...BlaView.init(BlaView.java:89)
       at ...BlaView.(BlaView.java:85)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17483)
       at ...BlaView.init(BlaView.java:89)
       at BlaView.(BlaView.java:85)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/layer_bla_bla.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020174
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2139)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:810)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:618)
       at ...TypefacedTextView.(TypefacedTextView.java:22)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17483)
       at ...BlaView.init(BlaView.java:89)
       at ...BlaView.(BlaView.java:85)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/vector_in_bla_bla.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02031f
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2139)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
       at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:159)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:939)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:879)
       at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2515)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2135)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:810)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:618)
       at ...TypefacedTextView.(TypefacedTextView.java:22)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17483)
       at ...BlaView.init(BlaView.java:89)
       at ...BlaView.(BlaView.java:85)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:935)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:879)
       at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2515)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2135)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
       at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:159)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:939)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:879)
       at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2515)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2135)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:810)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:618)
       at ...TypefacedTextView.(TypefacedTextView.java:22)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17483)
       at ...BlaView.init(BlaView.java:89)
       at ...BlaView.(BlaView.java:85)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at ...BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:71)
       at ...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: using `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`?

Comment: Yes, compileSdkVersion 24 buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

Comment: did you set the drawable programmatically? AFAIK setting drawable is no longer work except using `app:scrCompat`, so it no longer possible for example set vector drawable as drawableLeft/Right for OS pre lollipop

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you may have upgraded from Support Library 23.2.0, after which there were a couple of changes made. Quoting from [Chris Banes' article](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.g7dbnzs43):

> First up, this functionality was originally released in 23.2.0, but then we found some memory usage and Configuration updating issues so we it removed in 23.3.0. In 23.4.0 (technically a fix release) we’ve re-added the same functionality but behind a flag which you need to manually enable.
>
> If you want re-enable this, just stick this at the top of your Activity:
>
> static  {
>
> AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromSourcesEnabled(true);
>
> }

The functionality mentioned here is the ability to use `VectorDrawables` in various places like layer-lists. If you want to continue, you'll need to paste that code snippet into each Activity that you want it to be enabled for.

Comment: Hi @Lewis McGeary Thanks for the answer, i knew this solution but haven't tried it yet because exception is almost impossible to reproduce on any pre-lolipop device/emulator.

However i will try this as a probable crash fix but my problem is that my project has more than 100 activities.

So i was thinking that if there is a way to use it in Application class and use this globally in project, i haven't tried but would it work like this because putting this snippet in every activity is nearly impossible for me.

Comment: Yikes!  I'm not sure if doing it in the Application class would work or not. If you do need to put it in every Activity, then it sounds like a good use for Structural Search & Replace in Android Studio. You should be able to search for all classes that extend AppCompatActivity (or whatever your project uses) and insert the snippet.

Comment: Thats a long story then, let me try application way first.

Comment: I figured a way deal with this, i forgot that in my project i have a base class which all activities extends, `BaseActivity` is an `AppCompatActivity`. So Win-Win!! Thanks

Comment: Hey that's great!