# Android Invalid drawable tag vector on drawableStart

Tags: android, vector, android-drawable, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

Here's my button:

```
<com.rey.material.widget.Button
android:id="@+id/joinOccasionBTN"
style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave.Light"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_envelope"
android:drawablePadding="2dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:onClick="goToOccasion"
android:padding="20dp"
android:text="@string/join"
app:rd_enable="true"
app:rd_rippleType="wave" />
```

Here's `ic_envelope`:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="58.0"
android:viewportWidth="58.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#E95853" android:pathData="M27.14,0.73L0,26v0.04h58v-0.04L30.86,0.73C29.81,-0.24 28.19,-0.24 27.14,0.73z"/>
<path android:fillColor="#C64645" android:pathData="M0,26.04h58v31.96h-58z"/>
<path android:fillColor="#D75A4A" android:pathData="M0.09,26.05l57.51,31.71c-0.03,0.13 -0.03,0.11 -0.06,0.24H0.13C0.06,58 0,57.94 0,57.87l0,-31.77C0,26.06 0.05,26.03 0.09,26.05z"/>
<path android:fillColor="#ED7161" android:pathData="M57.91,26.05L29,41.99l28.6,15.77c-0.03,0.13 -0.03,0.11 -0.06,0.24h0.33C57.94,58 58,57.94 58,57.87V26.1C58,26.06 57.95,26.03 57.91,26.05z"/>
```

And finally the error:

```
Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
```

Which occurs on setting the layout
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `drawableStart` doesn't work with Vectors on pre-lollipop; which crashed my app. Removing that was the solution for me and the **only solution** since the only way to use them are with `app:srcCompat` and `setImageResource()`, which doesn't work for `drawableX`.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. It's not the only solution, using them in other places has been disabled by default because of "some memory usage and Configuration updating issues" but can be enabled. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40052617/5251523